# Series with complex part

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-i)^n}{n} 
$$
I tried the ratio test and the root test, but both are not working.
What else could I try?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what's the purpose of your edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-i)^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{n} i^n = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{2n} + i\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}
$$
and study the convergence of both terms (real and complex parts) using the alternating series test.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Both terms converge, so the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

We write the given series on this form 
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{e^{-in\pi/2}}{n}$$
and we apply [the Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).